# PySerial and microcontroller

Tags: python, microcontroller, pic, pyserial, uart

I'm trying to communicate with an MCU via UART with pySerial.
I use an Arduino USB2Serial Light Converter to send the data from PC to my PIC33F.
Because of the Arduino Converter I cant use CTS or RTS.

I managed to send data to the MCU and also receive data from it. But the problem is
the data isn't always what it should be.

For example I want to send a whole string from the MCU to the terminal but what I get is not the string given in the code of the MCU programm. Another problem is
that NO comparison between characters work. Which means I send a character to the MCU and the MCU compares it with a character to make decisions.

Ok now to some code:

#### 1. Send string from PIC33F to PC and read it with pySerial

```
putsU1("string");

// print a string

    int putsU1(char *s) {
     while(*s)
        putU1(*s++); 
    }

// print a character

    int putU1(int c) {
      while (_UTXBF);
        U1TXREG = c;
      return c; 
    }
```

The result I get for this code if I read it via `pySerial` is the following;

```
In [13]: ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, bytesize=7, xonxoff=0)

In [14]: while True:                                                     
            print(struct.unpack('s', ser.read()))
         ....:     
('\x7f',)
('c',)
('\x11',)
('\t',)
('e',)
('y',)
('=',)
('\x7f',)
```

#### 2. Send data to PIC33F with `pySerial` and echo it back

This one works only for single characters and not for strings. Also the characters echoed back are switching randomly between uppcase and lowercase.

```
     getsnU1(s, BUF_SIZE);

     char *getsnU1(char *s, int len) {
        char *p = s;
        int cc = 0;
        do {
           *s = getU1();
           putU1(*s);

           if ((*s == 0x8) && (s > p)) {
              putU1(' ');
              putU1(0x8);
              len++;
              s--;
              continue;
           }

           if (*s == '\n')
              continue;

           if (*s == '\r')
              break;
           s++;
          len--;
       } while (len > 1);

      *s = '\0';

      return p;
    }
```

The UART configuration:

```
#define FOSC            8000000
#define FCY             (FOSC/2)
#define BAUD            9600
#define U1BRGValue      (((FCY/BAUD)/16)-1)

void initUART1(void) {
/* general UART config */
RPINR18bits.U1RXR = U1RXPIN;            // set RP5 as UART1 RX
_RP6R = 0b00011;                        // set RP6 as UART Tx pin
U1RXPINTRIS = 1;                        // set RP5 (RB5) as input
U1MODEbits.PDSEL = DATAPARITY;           // set data bits and parity
U1MODEbits.STSEL = STOPBITS;            // set stop bits
U1MODEbits.ABAUD = 0;                   // auto-baud disabled
U1MODEbits.BRGH = 0;                    // low speed baud rate
U1BRG = U1BRGValue;                     // set baud value


/* enable interrupt on error */
IEC4bits.U1EIE = 1;                     // enable UART1 error interrupt
IPC16bits.U1EIP = 6;                     // set interrupt priority to 6

/* enable RX buffer interrupt */
IEC0bits.U1RXIE = 0;                    // enable UART1 RX interrupt
U1STAbits.URXISEL = 0b00;                // interrupt flag is set when buffer is 3/4 full
IPC2bits.U1RXIP = 6;                     // set interrupt priority to 6

/* enable TX interrupt */
IEC0bits.U1TXIE = 0;


/* enable UART1 module */
U1MODEbits.UEN = 0b00;
U1MODEbits.UARTEN = 1;
_UTXEN = 1;                             // enable UART Tx
```

}

I'm kinda frustrated because I can't figure out where the problem lies. Been testing and reading for hours and everywhere it seems so simple to get this up and running but it just wont on my end ;(.
I tried to write data to the PIC33F with `serial.write('text'.encode('ascii'))` and
`serial.write(struct.pack('s',('test')))` which all produce the same results.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Voting to close as "Too Localized" because of OP's statement here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10967884/616736

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want bytesize=7 (unless you know exactly why).

Also, a classical problem with UARTs is that individual characters work, but whole strings don't - this is usually when the receiving microcontroller does only buffer a single character in hardware. I don't know PIC, but in that code above where you do getU1() followed by putU1() I guess that putU1() waits for the duration of one character, so when you call getU1() again later you will have missed the one character (if the software did send it without pause).

My usual workaround is something like:

```
def write(s):
    for c in s:
        ser.write(c)
        time.sleep(0.001) # often not required
```

In general pyserial seems to work okay for all my projects, but you should also check with a normal terminal program to be sure. Apart from that I can only suggest you double-check the baudrate and FOSC on your microcontroller.

Comment: Your right with that! The function getsnU1 also uses the getU1, which means one character at a time.

I have to use a bytesize of 7 because if i dont i wouldnt get any readable data from the PIC. This is kind of strange because the PIC works with a bytesize of 8.

I tried to implement a software controll flow to get rid of some wierd behavior but it aint working because the comparison of the received characters aint working.

if (c == '\x11') --> not working with serial.write('\x11')

putsU1("string\n");  --> results in a output like s\x7f\tr\x7fi\x7fng

And the byte \x7f appears randomly